# Use Assetic in Symfony for js files

Tags: php, symfony

I am including js files in this way below but seems nothing is included and I don't have errors.

```
{% javascripts 'web/js/*' %}
     <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

The path is applicationName/web/js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the best practice on Symfony documentation I solved in this way :

```
{% stylesheets 'assets/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

where the folder assets/css is in Symfony web folder.